# Squaring pixels of GeoTIFF using GDAL

Tags: raster, gdal, resampling

I have a GeoTiff that has been supplied to me with non square pixels (I suspect due to reprojection to lat lon at some point). However the next step in my processing chain requires a Arc ASCII grid as input and so I need square pixels.

To save me trying to guess the original projection can any one tell me how to use GDAL to resample my image so the pixels become square?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not something I've tried, but I think you can do it with `gdalwarp`:

```
gdalwarp -tr 10.0 -10.0 -r bilinear src.tif dst.asc
```

You would choose a `-tr` value based on the smallest value of the source's resolution, remembering to negate the y scale if it's a top-down image. `gdal_translate` has an `-outsize` parameter that might do the job, but it may just truncate the image, or at best use nearest neighbour interpolation.

I'd be interested in what you find, because sooner or later it's going to happen to someone else!

Comment: This works nicely, only issue is that you can't translate to ascii grid with gdalwarp so you need an intermediate tif and then use gdal_translate.

Comment: I'm glad it works! Shame about the two-stage process, but that's the nature of text-based formats I guess.

Comment: There is -tr parameter in gdal_translate for setting the target resolution and -r parameter for selecting the resampling method, both documented in http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html.