# Transforming raster with gdal.Warp

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, osgeo

I am trying to transform a raster with  `gdal.Warp` in my own python script.

Example:

In the src raster one pixel presents 5 meters and I am trying to transform it where one pixel would present 6,5 meters. I am reading the gdal python documentations and don't know how to actually do this.

Should I just calculate the new width and height from the ratio of 5/6,5 and use it in the `gdal.WarpOptions` or is there a parameter that takes the pixel per meter data?

What is the `dstSRS` parameter ?

Comment: related question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27924/squaring-pixels-of-geotiff-using-gdal

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time.  I would [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/348624/edit) out your 2nd question about `dstSRS` but @IanTurton has answered that part of it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`WarpOptions`](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#WarpOptions) has `xRes` and `yRes` arguments (output x & y resolution).

You can either create a `WarpOptions` object and pass it to `gdal.Warp` with the `options=your_warp_options` argument or you can just pass `xRes` & `yRes` directly to `gdal.Warp` as keyword  arguments:

```
options = gdal.WarpOptions(xRes=6.5, yRes=6.5, your other args, eg. resampleAlg=gdal.GRA_Bilinear)
gdal.Warp(destDS, srcDS, options=options)
```

Or

```
gdal.Warp(destDS, srcDS, xRes=6.5, yRes=6.5, your other args, eg. resampleAlg=gdal.GRA_Bilinear)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still have some troubles with the warp func. What kind of objects are destDS and srcDS. Can srcDS be a numpy array ?

Comment: Either a `gdal.Dataset` (opened in write mode for `destDS` or read mode for `srcDS`) or file paths for either. No, you can't use a numpy array. Please ask further questions as new questions.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this I always find that the documentation of the GDAL utility helps me work out what the Python is expecting. So looking at the [gdalwarp page](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html) leads me to suspect that `dstSRS` is the same as the [`-t_srs` argument](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-t-srs) so it's looking for the target SRS (or CRS) - in your case probably the same as the input one.

Comment: don't confuse srcDS, source dataset, with dstSRS, the destination spatial reference system