# Proximity distance calculation error

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, error, proj, proximity

I am trying to calculate the proximity distance for my road layer. I have already converted the vector layer in raster, with the units in meters. However, when I try to run the proximity distance tool, I get this error
Error: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
Warning 1: Pixels not square, distances will be inaccurate.

The resulting image is a raster with a value 0 and it doesn't overlay to the existing layer. How to fix this problem?

Comment: so you have 2 problems: 1) Proj is not installed or is not where QGis expects to find it `Error: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db` and 2) your pixels are not square which will mean that the distances will be wrong `Warning 1: Pixels not square, distances will be inaccurate.`  for the 2nd one - https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/27924/79 - may help